# ido-like restrict to matches while completing

Tags: completion

When using ido, the command `ido-restrict-to-matches` (bound to `C-SPC`) is one of my favourite. What it does: instead of completing input against the initial collection of things, it will:

- restrict that collection to the list of those things that match[*] the current input, and
- remove the current input.

This allows to narrow down the list incrementally.

I would love to see such a mechanism work with the default completion system of emacs (I'm in particular interested in `icomplete-mode`). Does it exist, or how to do it ?

[*] Or, with a prefix arg, those that do not match (should be available in emacs-25.1, yet unreleased).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the answer is *no*; it does not exist for vanilla Emacs completion, and likewise for `icomplete-mode`.  (Someone will correct me if I'm wrong.)

This kind of narrowing is a key feature of [Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles), which Icicles calls [*progressive completion*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion).

Some other completion UIs now provide such a feature, including [Helm](https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm) and, as you point out, Ido. Icicles was the first to provide this feature, AFAIK; it has had it for almost a decade now.

A related feature is to narrow, not by matching additional patterns, but by **not** matching additional patterns. Icicles calls this [*chipping away the non-elephant*](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Nutshell_View#ChippingAway).

Here, you match an additional pattern and then subtract those matches from the previous ones. This can be a powerful way to quickly narrow a set of completion candidates by simply weeding out those that match certain patterns.

---

*Note:* Unlike Ido completion and Icomplete completion, Icicles completion is very close to "*the default completion system of emacs*". It uses the minibuffer the same way (you can edit there etc.), and it uses buffer `*Completions*` the same way.

In fact, if you just use `TAB` for completion and you do not use any of the Icicles-specific minibuffer keys, the completion behavior is pretty much the same as vanilla Emacs.

So Icicles really does provide something very close to vanilla Emacs completion plus, by hitting `S-SPC`, progressive completion (incremental narrowing).

Comment: I totally agree that "chipping away the non-elephant" is a very useful and desirable feature. In fact, I actually use that feature a lot with ido (using a patch waiting to be included in emacs. See emacs bug#15631).

Comment: Btw I'll accept this answer soon, and later change my mind if someone comes up with an implementation of the feature :)

Comment: That (chipping away) will be a welcome addition to Ido.

Comment: Indeed, AFAIK the answer is no, and it's a feature I'd be happy to see added to minibuffer.el.